# record audio in java and determine real time if a tone of x frequency was played if so do something

Tags: java, audio, real-time, fft, audio-recording

I want to be able to detect a tone of a predetermined frequency using java.  What I am doing is playing a tone (the frequency of the tone is variable by user input) and I am trying to detect if the tone is of a certain frequency.  If it is, I execute a certain method.  From what I have read I will need to us FFT, but I'm not sure how to implement it in java.  There seems to be a lot of documentation for how to do it, but what documentation there is involves looking at an audio file rather than real time analysis.  I don't need to save the audio to a file just determine if and when a tone of frequency x was recorded.

Ideally I would like to record at a sample rate of 44KHz and after determining if a tone was detected, determine when the tone was detected with an accuracy of +-3ms.  However, an accuracy less than this would be acceptable as long as it isn't ridiculous (ie +100ms).  I know roughly what I need to do from what I have looked up, but I need help tying it all together.  Using pseudo code it would look roughly like this (I think)

Note that I know roughly within +-1s of when a tone of satisfying frequency maybe detected

```
for(i = 0, i < 440000 * 2, i++){//*2 because of expected appearance interval;may change
    record sound sample
    fft(sound sample)
    if(frequencySoundSample > x){
        do something
        return
    }
}
```

There will be considerable background noise while the tone is played.  However the tone will have a very high frequency, like 15-22KHz, so it is my belief that by simply looking for when the recorder detects a very high frequency I can be sure it is my tone (also the tone will be played with a high amplitude for maybe .5s or 1s).  I know that there will not be other high frequency sounds as background noise (I am expecting a background frequency high of maybe 5KHz).

I have two questions then.  Is the pseudo code that I have provided sufficient for what I want to do?  If it isn't or if there is a better way of doing this I'm all for it.  Second, how would I implement this in java?  I understand what I need to do, but I'm having trouble tying it all together.  I'm pretty decent with java but I'm not familiar with the syntax involved with audio and I don't have any experience with fft.  Please be explicit and give code with comments.  I've been trying to figure this out for a while I just need to see it all tied together.  Thank you.

EDIT

I understand that using a for loop like I have will not produce the frequency that I want.  It was more to show roughly what I want.  That is, recording, performing fft, and testing the frequency all at once as time progresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking for a specific frequency then an FFT-based method is probably a bad choice for your particular application, for two reasons:

1. it's overkill - you're computing an entire spectrum just to detect the magnitude at one point
2. to get 3 ms resolution for your onset detection you'll need a large overlap between successive FFTs, which will require much more CPU bandwidth than just processing successive blocks of samples

A better choice for detecting the presence or absence of a single tone is the [Goertzel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) (aka Goertzel filter). It's effectively a DFT evaluated at a single frequency domain bin, and is widely used for tone detection. It's *much* less computationally expensive than an FFT, very simple to implement, and you can test its output on every sample, so no resolution problem (other than those dictated by the laws of physics). You'll need to low pass filter the magnitude of the output and then use some kind of threshold detection to determine the onset time of your tone.

Note that there are a number of useful questions and answers on SO already about tone detection and using the Goertzel algorithm (e.g. [Precise tone onset/duration measurement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456855/precise-tone-onset-duration-measurement/4461542#4461542)) - I suggest reading these along with the Wikipedia entry as a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Im actually working on a similar project with pitch detection, in Java as well.  If you want to use FFT, you could do it with these steps.  Java has a lot of libraries that can make this process easy for you.

First, you need to read in the sound file.  This can be done using Java Sound.  It's a built in library with functions that make it easy to record sound.  Examples can be found [here](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/audio_playing_recording.html).  The default sample rate is 44,100 KHz (CD quality).  These examples can get you from playing the actual tone to a double array of bytes representing the tone.

Second, you should take the FFT with JTransforms.  Here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/jongukim/4037243) of FFT being taken on a collection of samples.

FFT gives you an array twice the length of the array of samples you passed it.  You need to go through the FFT array by two's, since each part of this array is represented as an imaginary and a real piece.  Compute the magnitude of each part of this array with sqrt(im^2 + re^2).  Then, find which magnitude is the largest.  The index of that magnitude corresponds to the frequency you're looking for.

Keep in mind, you don't take FFT on the entire portion of sound.  You break the sound up into chunks, and FFT each one.  The chunks can overlap for higher accuracy, but that shouldn't be a problem, since you're just looking for a predetermined note.  If you want to improve performance, you can also window each chunk before doing this.

Once you have all the FFTs, they should confirm a certain frequency, and you can check that against the note you want.

If you want to try and visualize this, I'd suggest using JFreeChart.  It's another library that makes it easy to graph things.